# clojure: use a binding in cond to place recur in tail position only?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have some code that's currently giving me an error, because recur can only be in the tail position. here's the function:

```
(defmethod transposer
    Long [scale degree]
    (loop [new-scale scale count degree]
    (cond 
        (zero? count) new-scale 
        (< count 0) (recur (step (reverse new-scale)) (inc count)))
        :else (recur (step new-scale) (dec count))))
```

One way I can think to fix this is conditional binding, if I could say:
*when count is less than zero, set count-operator to "inc", otherwise set to "dec", then recur at the end.*

Then this would fix my problem. But I'm not sure how to do this in clojure, or if it's even possible, when-let and if-let don't seem to do this. What is the best way to fix my code to only use one recur?

EDIT: A couple of things I learned here:

1) "recur" will recur back to the defn, if there's no loop statement. In the book I read, all the examples of recur use loop/recur, so I thought it was necessary to have a loop. it's not, my loop statement want superfluous.

2) Getting the parentheses wrong gave me a confusing error, it struck me as strange that both cond statements wouldn't be considered to be at the tail, since they are mutually exclusive. I should have paid a bit more attention to my paren completion checker.

3) If I ever do want to do conditional binding, I can use a standard "let" statement and just include the conditional logic there. coming from a java background, I sometimes forget the flexibility clojure allows in this area.

Comment: i don't understand your code.  `recur` inside a `loop` calls the loop, but your args list doesn't match.  and what is `do` for?

Comment: You also have an extra paren on the second to last line that should be on the last line.

Comment: apologies, the "do" was left over from some debugging I was doing, I've removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn foo [scale degree]
  (loop [new-scale scale count degree]
    (cond 
      (zero? count) new-scale 
      (< count 0) (recur (step (reverse new-scale)) (inc count))
      :else (recur (step new-scale) (dec count)))))
```

is closer to what you want, i think (it doesn't give the tail error; i used defn simply to test standalone).

there is no problem with multiple `recur`s - tail recursion doesn't mean it has to be on the last line of text, only that there is no more calculation to do when it returns.

the main problem was messed up parens (too many after `count`).  i'd suggest getting an editor that auto-indents (and using auto-indent obsessively).  that would have shown the parens problem immediately (i use la clojure plugin in intellij idea, but i am sure others have similar functionality).

update: why is the `loop` needed at all?

```
(defn foo [scale degree]
  (cond 
    (zero? degree) scale 
    (< degree 0) (recur (step (reverse scale)) (inc degree))
    :else (recur (step scale) (dec degree))))
```

Comment: hmmm, I don't think my recur arguments are wrong, there should be two, values for new-scale and count. the "scale" and "degree" are their intial values. both my recur statements pass two params. am I missing something?

Comment: oh, sorry, you're right.  i don't use it myself much.  updated.

Comment: but in that case, why loop?!?!

Comment: I'm looping because I'm still mutating their values. thanks for the paren catch, that was indeed my problem! I'm using vim with rainbow parens, and just missed this somehow. much appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand the mutation argument.  you don't refer to the previous values, that i can see.

Comment: You are using recursion, not mutation -- `recur` is "calling" `loop` with new values, not mutating `new-scale` and `count`.  It would work equally well without the loop.  The only possible issue is if you use `scale` and `degree` in the body of the `loop`, but you don't.

Comment: ahhhh, I see what you're saying. I can remove the loop statement and it will just revert to recurring on the function, and that will work just fine for this case. cool, I will do this!

Answer (score 3):

In your original question, you asked "One way I can think to fix this is conditional binding, if I could say: when count is less than zero, set count-operator to "inc", otherwise set to "dec", then recur at the end." and no one answered that part:

```
(let [d (if (neg? degree) inc dec)]
  (recur (step scale) (d degree)))
```

Except that you want to call reverse in one case and not the other so you need a conditional binding for that too. Here's an example binding both using destructuring:

```
(let [[s d] (if (neg? degree) [reverse inc] [identity dec])]
  (recur (step (s scale)) (d degree)))
```

Although as Andrew Cooke pointed out, a simple cond with recur in each 'tail' (and no loop) works just fine.

Comment: thanks sean. looking at your example, it seems obvious I could have included an if inside the let, but it just didn't occur to me to do that. thanks!